# Table-Driven Lexers - What about reserved keywords?

Tags: compiler-construction, grammar, lexer, lexical-analysis, formal-languages

This question stems from another question I have asked over on the CS site. [Reference](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/121983/table-driven-lexer-and-the-classification-table)

I have tried searching through online course notes from various Universities so that I can find the answer to a problem I am facing.

I have to implement a compiler for a custom language for an assignment. This language contains some **atomic** symbols like letters from the English alphabet, and digits. And I managed to find examples for these, and they're quite straightforward. For example: [Go to Page 25](http://www.cs.um.edu.mt/%7Esspi3/CompTheory-003.pdf)

However, this language also contains **reserved words** such as **if** and **for**.

This is where I'm having problems. Suppose the lexer is trying to read the string "**if** (*expression*) statement". If I use an implementation like [Page 4](https://www.cs.oberlin.edu/%7Ebob/cs331/Class%20Notes/February/February%203/Table-Driven%20Scanners.pdf) it will incorrectly categorise **if** as an identifier.

So my idea is to implement a "lookahead" mechanism so that before the lexer categorises and sends to the DFA what is being read, it can make an informed, correct decision.

For example: The lexer encounters **i**. Since **i** can belong to a reserved word (**if**), the lexer should check for the *next* character. If it is **f** then the lexer should make sure it's not actually a normal string that happens to start with **if**, like ifxyz.

I like this idea, except I haven't managed to find anything similar from looking at course notes online, which makes me think that perhaps I'm doing something wrong.

**UPDATE!!**
This is for those who got here through a search trying to find a solution.
It's been a while, I've actually solved the issue and the answer linked in the comments is **very** helpful. I suggest you go read it.

Here's how I ended up solving this:

---

> START(f) -> F
>
> F(o) -> FO
>
> FO(r) -> FOR
>
> FOR(_) -> IDENTIFIER

Furthermore, all states have a "Lex As" property.
Reason for this: Consider you arrive at state F with no further input. Therefore, you should assume it's an identifier (in most languages).
Hence, *F.lexAs* would return the correct interpretation of the state, in this case, IDENTIFIER.

Comment: Answered [here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/121993/4416) on [cs.se]

Comment: If you got here with a search, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52044858/1566221) might also be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lookahead example really is just like a DFA in itself. Sadly, there is no easy way to solve this problem besides hard coding the keywords into the DFA you are using.

For the `if` example, I would make a token type called `IF` which is different from your `ID` token type.

Now, you must change your DFA to accept an `IF` token. If we are at the starting state and we read an `i` the DFA should not start the normal ID path, it should go down a separate path.

Here's an example DFA for interpreting just the `IF` and `ID` tokens, and accepting only characters `a-z`.

[image: Keyword DFA]

Comment: I've since solved the issue, and (as linked in the question's comments) this is pretty much the solution I went for.